# Will the firefox os emulator be detected by running adb devices command?

Tags: android, firefox, android-emulator, emulation, firefox-os

I'm currently doing a project and I'm wondering if I can push the files I get from the device to the emulator and read them.

I know that if you run the emulator of Android, the system can detect it by running adb devices command, but I have tried the b2g desktop client and the firefox add-on simulator, they didn't work.

I haven't built an emulator myself, do you think the emulator will be detected?

And also, can I build the real emulator on Windows?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

B2G Desktop client and FxOS Simulator are the same, they're not real emulators but are simply loading whatever profile you ask them to load.

On the other hand you can build the "real" emulator (there are 2 flavors: x86 or arm), that's basically the same emulator than Android's emulator, and you see it with adb.

Building an emulator is just like building a full Firefox OS image. You can look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Preparing_for_your_first_B2G_build#Configuring_the_B2G_build_for_an_emulator for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox OS **simulator** won't be detected by ADB because it does not emulate an Android runtime (note it's different from the Android **emulator**).

I don't really know what kind of files you want to push to the simulator so I'm not too sure how to answer your question, though.

Comment: I'm doing a digital forensics project with firefox os. I'm thinking that if I can get the data of the phone as image files and push them to the emulator, so that the data of the device can be viewed on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there actually is a Firefox OS emulator and executing

adb devices

should list the emulator if it's running. You might need a debug build for this to work.

You can at least push and pull files from and to a running emulator. Using them is another topic: the emulation is very slow and that might be a problem for certain tasks (e.g., multimedia).